# Setting Angular2-style attributes on HTML node

Tags: angularjs, dom, angular, setattribute, svg.js

I am migrating an application from Angular1 to Angular2, in which I used the svg.js library to draw an SVG. Some elements of the SVG contained "ng-click" directives, that I made the SVG library print to the final SVG.

That worked alright in Angular1, however, now the directive is called "(click)" and everything breaks. I traced the SVG sources and found that the following call

```
this.node.setAttribute(attr, value.toString())
```

results in the following error message:

```
VM22161:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '(click)' is not a valid attribute name.(…)
```

Any ideas to solve that problem? Patching the SVG source would be ok for me, if there's no other way.

Comment: Can you please add more code. Hard to see what's going on with this small fragments.

Comment: I'm sorry. I guess everything boils down to the fact, that the setAttribute() function does now allow attribute names to start with a bracket. If I am right, the node object is provided by the API of browser's engine, which makes it pretty complicated.

Comment: I found another solution for that issue. The binding syntax of Angular2 allows to use "on-click" instead of "(click)".

Comment: You can add that as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A valid and quick workaround is to use the binding syntax of Angular2, that allows to use "on-click" instead of "(click)".